# Integration problem where denominator of the integral variable is fractional powered

Tags: calculus, integration

I am a bit stuck on this integration problem

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{a+(x-b)^c} dx
\end{equation}

Is there a name on this type of integral that I can look up to?

Comment: It can be reduced to $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^c}$ which for rational values of $c$ boils down to a partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
I=\int \frac{dx}{a+(x-b)^c} =\int \frac{dy}{a+y^c} =\frac{y }{a}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{c};1+\frac{1}{c};-\frac{y^c}{a}\right)
\end{equation}

where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: Didn't expect it to be hypergeometric function! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Crushh. You are very welcome !